# CKEditor icons corrupted

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am trying to migrate to ckeditor 4.3.2. full package

If a look at sample page "ckeditor/samples/replacebyclass.html" directly by browser:

```
file:///Z:/home/mysite/public_html/ckeditor/samples/replacebyclass.html
```

Everything is correct.

But when this page is outputed by WAMP:

```
http://mysite/ckeditor/samples/replacebyclass.html
```

Every icon in toolbar is shifted or missed([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raZCg.jpg))

Does anybody has any ideas?

Comment: did you checked all files are included properly like css/js ?

Comment: This is the one demo-file from 'ckeditor/samples' directory. Only difference is way to display it. So all css and js files are included the same way and 'from the box'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in browser cache of moono/icons.png
Previuos version of this file was cached. 
I forced browser to reload file and now it works.

Finally i wrote this code to avoid such problem in the future:

```
try {
    var _img = new Image();
    _img.src = "/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png";//preload fresh copy of icons
    _img.onload = function() {
    $( 'textarea' ).ckeditor();};
} catch (e) { }
```